# 9 speed Shimano (shifter+derailleur) + 8 speed cassette

Tags: cassette, derailleur-rear, shifter, compatibility

At the moment I have a wheel with a Shimano 8speed cassette (HG30-8I) (11-30 or 32T)

and also I have following rear derailleurs:

- XTR  (RD-M952) (9 sp) GS
- Altus (RD-M310)(7/8 sp) SGS

**Questions:**

- Number of speed for shifters(I will buy 2nd hand)

  [*I would prefer 9speed shifters if they are compatible*]
- type of Chain to buy

**Notes:**
Bicycle is an old MTB with 3 chain rings
Originally it was 7 speed, but rear wheel was stolen.
I assume that 7 speed chain as to be replaced

Specs
**XTR  (RD-M952)**

- Rapid Rise   no
- Speeds   9-Speed
- Max Sprocket     34T
- Min Sprocket     11T
- Front Difference     22T max.
- Total Capacity   33T(GS)

**Altus RD-M310**

- Ideal Use: MTB, city, hybrid bikes
- Compatibility: 7-speed, 8-speed
- Mount Type: Standard mount
- Cage: Long cage (SGS)
- Maximum Sprocket: 34 teeth
- Total Capacity: 43 teeth
- Pulleys: 13 teeth G-pulley, 15 teeth T-pulley
- Clutch: No

Comment: Also have a look at the below question.  One of the answers explains a "hack" in which the 9 speed XTR shifter can be used on 8 speed cassette.  In case you get stuck and can only source a 9 speed shifter rather than a 8 speed.  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/can-i-use-a-9-speed-shifter-with-a-8-speed-cassette

Answer (score 6):

You can't match a 9-speed shifter with an 8-speed cassette. The spacing between gears will be larger than the spacing between shifts.

Your options are:

1. Buy an 8-speed shifter
2. Buy a 9-speed shifter and a 9-speed cassette

If you go with option 1, either of your derailleurs will work. (The derailleur is basically just a spring, so the spacing of shifts doesn't matter.)

If you go with option 2, you'll probably want to use your XTR. The Altus *might* work, but I wouldn't be surprised if the tension wasn't tight enough on the derailleur and the shifting wasn't very precise.

A 9-speed chain should work fine regardless of which setup you go with.

Comment: I am not sure about "derailleur is basically just a spring, so the spacing of shifts doesn't matter."  As in the past I tried without luck to add the XTR to a combination of 6speed freewheel and 6speed shifter (microshift) but i was having noises at some speeds and it was not able to reach last cog.

Comment: @DanielPerez That is, admittedly, an oversimplification. Within the context of 8-9 speed everything is close enough that the derailleurs are more or less interchangeable. A six speed setup is a big jump though and pull ratios, cog sizes, and overall travel become factors.

Answer (score 6):

Bike gears are very confusing.

5, 6, 7, 8 speed cassettes maintain roughly the same horizontal gap between cogs, so the shifter just has to pull more wire and the RD has to move further horizontally.

8+9+10 speed cassettes share the same total width.  To do so, the space between cogs shrinks meaning the chain gets narrower as speeds increase.  Upside is an 8 speed bike can be upgraded to 10 speed without changing the hub.

11 and 12 and more is a crapshoot of weirdness where even the MTB and road groupsets diverge from each other.

---

The XTR is a "better" unit than the altus, but they're both used.  Clean and lube both, looking for damage and wear.

In your place, I would either

1. just buy an 8 speed shifter and make it work while minimising cost.  You want an 8 speed chain.
2. upgrade to 9 speed with a suitable shifter and a 11-34 cassette.  You will need a 9 speed chain, shifter, and use the XTR.

Absolutely use new shift cabling inner and outer when re-doing the cabling.

Your 7 speed front mech and chainrings will not care too much about the 8 or 9 speed chain.  At worst it will be reluctant to change to the grannie ring on the triple.  I successfully upgraded a 3x5 = 15 speed bike to 3x9 and the front derailleur is workable after I reduced the cage width a little with pliers.

Comment: option2 seems optimal if i can reuse hub and just add 1(or change few) cog rings to the cassette. Or do i need to change the all the cogs on the cassette?.

Comment: @DanielPerez you'd need an entirely new 9 speed cassette.  The 8 speed spacing is about 0.2mm smaller (can't remember exact) so over 9 gears that's almost 2mm which screws up indexing.

Comment: @DanielPerez You can still use the current hub since a 9 speed cassette will fit on a freehub that held an 8 speed cassette.  You will need a 9 speed cassette (and shifter, and 9s chain) to have the correct inter-cog spacing.